# Scrollbar optimization vuejs

Tags: vue.js

i neem to optimize my scrollbar as much as i can, i found some solutions on github with virtual scrollview, but they working only with 1 column
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT04G.png)

But im need to work with grid
([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJN0N.png)) with ability to reactive add and remove elements. Maybe there are some solutions without virtual scrollview?

Comment: @Bерстак In which scenario you are using this grid? Could you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: @ThreeCheeseHigh you can checkout it on this site [link](https://tftrade.net/) (not advertise)